# Python - Rounding floating integers defined as variables and displaying them

Tags: python, django, view, rounding

I am trying to get this to calculate a number based on user input. While displaying it I want it to round to 2 digits. It refuses too! So confused. Any advice?

```
def calc(user_id):
numbers = {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'F': 0}
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
outs = Out.objects.filter(user=user)
counter = 0
total_number = 0
for out in outs:
if out.data['type'] != 'panel':
continue
else:
print out.data
total_number += numbers[out.data['level']]
counter += 1
x = round(float(total_number/float(counter)), 2)
user_profile.average = x
user_profile.save()
```

Comment: What exactly is getting displayed? This could be a case of floating-point math inaccuracy.

Comment: Please indent your code and add an example of your output

Answer (score 1):

Check this line of code:

```
total_number += numbers[out.data['level']]
```

if you are receiving a Keyerror, your problem is in that particular line. If you post your code indented, is going to be much more readable

```
def calc(user_id):

    numbers = {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'F': 0}
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    outs = Out.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = 0
    total_number = 0

    for out in outs:
        if out.data['type'] != 'panel':
            continue
        else:
            print out.data
        total_number += numbers[out.data['level']]
        counter += 1

    x = round(float(total_number/float(counter)), 2)
    user_profile.average = x
    user_profile.save()
```

## UPDATE

If you need precision, work with fixed and floating point arithmetic. check this module

> http://pymotw.com/2/decimal/

Also, its posible that your round command works correctly but your number cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point. If you need to print the number you can use:

```
"%.1f" % n
```

Comment: There is no error presented, it generates but it simply doesn't round the number. Thank you for the indents! I will make sure to do that next time.

Comment: You are welcome, please edit your post with more details like examples of your output or little pieces of data input

Comment: Also you dont need to cast to float twice in float(total_number/float(counter)). Just put round(total_number/float(counter), 2). Maybe that's causing your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to use round().

The string formatting is the way to go.  See here: [Formatted strings for rounding in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938747/formatted-strings-for-rounding-in-python)